# Why is my collection view cell returning the error "The dequeued cell is not an instance of TileCollectionViewCell"

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am building a collection view for my app via the storyboard and I have done the entire setup for the collection view. I created the `UICollectionViewController` and I have created a code file for the `UICollectionViewController`. I also created a code file for the prototype `CollectionViewCell` and I have assigned it a reuse identifier. I create a guard-let statement to detect any fatal error, and I have dequeued the `CollectionViewCell`.

I wrote this code above the class line, below the import statement.

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "TileCell"
```

I wrote this override function within the class.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TileCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TileCollectionViewCell")
    }

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

However, when I run the app in the simulator, it crashes and returns the and error from the guard-let statement into the console:

> The dequeued cell is not an instance of TileCollectionViewCell

Why is it returning this error?

Comment: That is most likely you have not registered the cel. Whenever you want to reuse a cel in tableview/collectionview, you have to register the cell. Usually you can do this in viewDidLoad. Look at the Silence answer. I think that will do what you need. If you are using a storyboard, you can also assign the identifier by selecting the UICollectionView

Answer (score 2):

Call `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` method when setup the collection view

```
collectionView.register(TileCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Check reusable identifier assigned in storyboard matches with "TileCell".
2. Check cell in the collection view has assigned to TileCollectionViewCell class in storyboard.